# HUAWEI FIDO Kit: Facial Authentication issue

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I implemented the Facial Authentication and they are failing, please check the below logs,

HMS SDK_com.huawei.hms.support.api.fido.bioauthn.FaceManager: getFaceRecognitionCapability not support.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. FIDO kit APIs are used in a library project's activity, so while using the FaceManager initialization instead of the library project activity, please try to use main app's activity (the activity which is we invoke face detection from main app).
2. Please change the face detection activities access specifier as public and try to access the face detection.